# My Docs edit caused a server error

Tags: bug, documentation

On the Swift "Subscripts" topic, I created a draft to move its only example to a different topic, thus deleting the topic. I got an error when trying to submit the draft, and now I get a server error when I try to load the page:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/2794/subscripts

redirects to

https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/swift/2794/subscripts

Comment: This might sound silly, but that link is to the error page. Have you tried going back to [the original page](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/2794/subscripts)?

Comment: Yeah, it redirects me to that error page.

Comment: No redirect for me at the moment, but this should be investigated anyway.

Comment: It probably only causes an error for me because I made the change (and presumably it tries to show me my not-yet-approved change).